# Change root of a branch in git

Tags: git, tags, branch, reset, rebase

I'm using git and want to change the base of an exiting branch. This is caused by a deployment system, which pulls this explicit branch into my production environment. When planning my releases, I create a tag every time I want to go live. But my branch has special changes too, so `git reset --hard v1.0` won't work.

Here a small example. I want this

```
      C---D---E deploy
     /
A---B---F---G master
     \
      v1.0
```

to become this

```
                          C---D---E deploy
                         /
A---B---F---G---H---I---J---K master
     \                   \
      v1.0                v1.1
```

Maybe `git rebase` is what I am looking for, but the man pages don't help me. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) should, like you say, allow you to change the base of deploy:

```
git checkout deploy
git rebase v1.1 # using the tag
(or:
 git rebase J # SHA1 of J
 or
 git rebase master~1
)
```

But you will end up with

```
C'---D'---E' deploy
```

That is, the SHA1 of the commits part of `deploy` branch are rewritten, which isn't too bad if nobody cloned said `deploy` branch and was working on it.
Since it is a branch for deployment, that is most likely the case (i.e. nobody was working on a clone of said branch).

Comment: But its not possible to use the tag name?!

Comment: @micha149: yes, I mistaken it for a branch name!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you'd want to lose your original branch. What I would do in such a case:

```
 # create a new branch from your 1.1 tag
 git checkout -b deploy1.1 v1.1 
 # merge your existing branch into this one
 git merge deploy
```

**EDIT**: added schema

You'll end up with something like that

```
       C---D---E deploy
       /        \_______ 
      /                  F deploy1.1
     /                  /
A---B---F---G--H--I--J--K--L
     \                   \
    v1.0                 V1.1
```

Comment: I don't want to loose it, because there are some important changes. Like a completely added Zend Framework Library, config of a database connection and other settings, wich I need only on the production system.

Comment: with my propositin, you keep your original branch and you got a new one merged on from J, meaning you can still modify your old 1.0-patched branch and work on the new one (in your drawing, you removed C - D - E, thus my question)

Comment: I actually like this solution better, if you need to keep track of each development effort needed for each deployment. (So +1) But if said development effort are always the same, a simple rebase would be enough.

Comment: The branch name in the production system is fixed. If I recreate the branch, the production system seems to lost the tracking. So, I prefer the rebase variant. Thx

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can use rebase to achieve the desired effect. the following command will checkout the `deploy` branch and replay all its commits, which are not reachable through `v1.1`, on top of `v1.1`:

```
git rebase v1.1 deploy
```

(the verbose way would be: `git rebase --onto v1.1 v1.0 deploy`)

but why rebasing and altering history? you can simply change the mainline of development into your deployment-branch:

```
git checkout deploy
git merge v1.1
```

this will leave all your commit hashes intact, your history will then look like this (`M` being the merge commit):

```
      C---D---E-----------M deploy
     /                   /
A---B---F---G---H---I---J---K master
     \                   \
      v1.0                v1.1
```

since conflicts might arise during rebase as well as during merge, you will have a history of merge conflicts when using the merge based approach. with rebase you don't have a history of conflicts which happened during rebase operation. using a merge based workflow, you can later see your conflicts in the (combined) diff of the merge commits.

Answer (score 2):

git rebase should work for you:

```
git checkout deploy
git rebase master~1
```

or

```
git rebase v1.1
```

Have a look at http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html - should help you understand rebase better I think