# move branch so that it branches off from master in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

i made a mistake so my branch now is:

```
master -> a -> b
```

but its suppose to be

```
master -> a
master -> b
```

now b has a's changes and now ive committed a bunch of stuff on b already. is there any way i can do  so branch b braches off from master and not from a?

Comment: Have a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712133/change-root-of-a-branch-in-git

Answer (score 1):

This exact situation is show as an example in `git rebase` manual:

```
git rebase --onto master a b
```